# Where to store json datas instead of using sqlite in android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am accessing the datas from json, storing the datas from json in sqlite and then retrieving it and display them on screen. It takes too long time for this process. Which is the better way to reduce the time consumption instead of storing and retrieving the datas from sqlite? Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: you can create .json file and access it

Answer (score 4):

You can store the JSON as plain text in a file.

A nice place to put them would be your application's cache directory.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

Answer (score 0):

You can store a JSON Data in a File or in a Shared Preference. Check [**Saving data in android training**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also use the file system to store json.  It can be easier for debugging as you can have the json.tostrong methods indent the json yo make it easier to read using the android file browser.

i make a filesystem class that accepts and returns json so apps just see the file system as a json store.